# PropertyValuesHolder: Couldn't find setter/getter for property alpha with value type float

Tags: android, animation

i thought nineoldandroids is a framework for API lower then HONEYCOMB...

so what do i wrong?? my HTC Android 2.2.1 throws this error (Couldn't find setter/getter for property alpha with value type float): on all these lines:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHintViewRing, "alpha", 0);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHintViewRing, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
```

EDIT:
i posted the wrong line sorry:

```
PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 1f, 0.1f);
```

was the bad one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries, i replaced all PropertyValuesHolder with ObjectAnimator (with float vars)

Comment: yes like i wrote. The property values holder makes the problem. so i userd an object animator object instead.