# Couldn't find setter property rotation for Button with value type float

Tags: android, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I am using NineOldAndroids to rotate a button when users click on it. here are the codes:

```
Button btntest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
        btntest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0f, 360f).start();
            }
        });
```

When I clicked on the button, it thrown this log into logcat:

```
10-24 05:25:42.394: E/PropertyValuesHolder(2387): Couldn't find setter property rotation for Button with value type float
```

I have took many searching but I didn't find any solution here.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the ObjectAnimator is available since **API level 11** . Your device is **API level 9** . Try running your code on device with at least Android 3.0+.

Comment: `Couldn't find setter property translationX for Button with value type float`. not work too. I am testing my app on Htc desire - android 2.3.

Comment: the `ObjectAnimator` is available since **API level 11** . Your device is **API level 9** . Try running your code on device with at least Android 3.0+

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the view doesn't ready?

Those code works fine on my device(4.3, Nexus4).

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing all PropertyValuesHolder with ObjectAnimator (with float vars) as per the answer here [PropertyValuesHolder: Couldn't find setter/getter for property alpha with value type float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13931443/1521424).

Or You might want to try the rotate animation below:

Create an Animation XML in the res/drawable/anim

**rotate_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<rotate
    android:duration="800"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Create a Rotate Animation.

```
private Animation rotate() {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NameOfActivity.this, R.anim.rotate_animation);
    return animation;
}
```

Then, use the rotate() animation in your button when the user clicks it.

```
Button btntest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    btntest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(rotate());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found my root cause. I am using both `NineOldAndroids` and `ActionbarSherlock`. And then, because `ActionbarSherlock` already include a part of NineOldAndroids, so I imported `com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator` instead of `com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator`.

`NineOldAndroids` works fine on all android SDK versions.